# Gradle : Copy resources folder from a dependency to the current project

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am new to gradle and I have a question.

I have a gradle project and in the dependencies there is an other project.

```
  ...

dependencies {
   compile group : 'abc' name : 'dependantProject' version : '1' configuration : 'runtime'
}
   ...
```

Now the `dependantProject` is a java project and has a resources folder , from which I want to copy a specific folder to the src/main/tests/resources folder of my current project.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a common java/groovy/kotlin project, or Android?

Comment: Its a java project.